# ¿Cómo puedo crear una notificación en android vía socket?

Tags: android, socket

he creado una app para android, creé un service para notificaciones, usando asyntask y llamando a un webservice y este da una respuesta json que luego es mostrada como una notificación pero es muy lento, mi hosting es remoto www.mihosting.com, mis preguntas son:

1- ¿Cómo creo el archivo para el servidor que escuche las peticiones recibidas?
2- ¿Cómo creo el archivo en android studio que llame al socket para recibir una respuesta y mostrarla como notificación?
3- ¿Cómo abro un puerto de escucha en el servidor remoto (cuenta con cpanel)?
4- ¿Cómo inicializo el socket en el servidor remoto?

Agradeceré mucho sus respuestas...

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de servidor estás corriendo?

Comment: El servidor remoto es linux